# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration. -- PC Name?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a few questions. I am having issues "tricking" the system to get to a PC Host.

In short:

I have a client who hired me to make software that incorporates Facebook into it. I am coding this in ASP.Net.

Now, I know that facebooks callback supports localhost, however, I would like it to redirect to: http:(slash slash)pcname-pc/Default.aspx

Is there a simple way to do this?

I am thinking I have to authorize it from a php web based, then forward the info to the local host to upload an image. But, will facebook's API allow me to use the tokens from a source that is not in the authorized callback list?